# c# loop until Console.ReadLine = 'y' or 'n'

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, console-application, string-comparison

I'm fairly new to c#, and writing a simple console app as practice. I want the application to ask a question, and only progress to the next piece of code when the user input equals 'y' or 'n'. Here's what I have so far.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string userInput;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Type something: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    }   while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput));

    Console.WriteLine("You typed " + userInput);
    Console.ReadLine();

    string wantCount;
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want me to count the characters present? Yes (y) or No (n): ");
        wantCount = Console.ReadLine();
        string wantCountLower = wantCount.ToLower();
    }   while ((wantCountLower != 'y') || (wantCountLower != 'n'));
}
```

I'm having trouble from `string wantCount;` onwards. What I want to do is ask the user if they want to count the characters in their string, and loop that question until either 'y' or 'n' (without quotes) is entered.

Note that I also want to cater for upper/lower case being entered, so I image I want to convert the wantCount string to lower - I know that how I currently have this will not work as I'm setting `string wantCountLower` inside the loop, so I cant then reference outside the loop in the `while`  clause.

Can you help me understand how I can go about achieving this logic?

Comment: `wantCountLower` is defined inside the scope of the do-while, so it isn't available outside. You need to define it before the loop (or better, use case-insensitive comparison).

Comment: i think you need to properly read up on how the while syntax works

Comment: `'y'` is the notation for the character you need `"y"` to check for the string.

Comment: prof1990, thanks for pointing out the use of incorrect punctuation. Takarii, your completely right - as I mention, I'm, still a rookie, but this is my preferred method of learning. Luaan, I wanted to do this but wasn't sure if I could assign it a valid value, since wantCount is assigned a value inside the loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could move the input check to inside the loop and utilise a `break` to exit. Note that the logic you've used will always evaluate to `true` so I've inverted the condition as well as changed your `char` comparison to a `string`.

```
string wantCount;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want me to count the characters present? Yes (y) or No (n): ");
    wantCount = Console.ReadLine();
    var wantCountLower = wantCount?.ToLower();
    if ((wantCountLower == "y") || (wantCountLower == "n"))
        break;
} while (true);
```

Also note the null-conditional operator (`?.`) before `ToLower()`. This will ensure that a `NullReferenceException` doesn't get thrown if nothing is entered.

Comment: There's been a few good responses which work, however I think this was what I was looking for - it fits best based around what I was trying to achieve. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare a character, then their is not need for `ReadLine` you can use `ReadKey` for that, if your condition is this :`while ((wantCountLower != 'y') || (wantCountLower != 'n'));` your loop will be an infinite one, so you can use `&&` instead for `||` here or it will be `while(wantCount!= 'n')` so that it will loops until you press `n`

```
char charYesOrNo;
do
{
   charYesOrNo = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
   // do your stuff here
}while(char.ToLower(charYesOrNo) != 'n');
```